# Dynamically change properties of View objects

Tags: android, android-layout, view, layout-inflater

On my activity's creation I have set an `AlphaAnimation` in order to perform some visual effects. Now I have set a `LayoutAnimationListener` and overriden the `onAnimationEnd()` method. The Animation is executed correctly and the callback to `onAnimationEnd()` is working as well. Within the `onAnimationEnd()` method I want to perform another animation on two child objects of the Activity's layout. These are two `EditText`s that are defined in XML with the property `android:visibility="gone"`. For starters, what I want to do is to have them set as `VISIBLE`.

I've tried getting a reference from their `parent`, change their `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and in the end invalidate the parent view.

This attempt does not seem to work. You will find the code attached below:

```
@Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd()");
            // TODO move icon up, make edittext's appear.

            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.splash_dialog_layout,
                    null);
            LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "Children" + linear.getChildCount());

            email = (EditText) linear.findViewById(R.id.splash_Email);
            email.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            pass = (EditText) linear.findViewById(R.id.splash_password);
            pass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            linear.invalidate();
            layout.invalidate();

            Splash_Activity.layout.invalidate();
        }
    };
```

I've tried to removeAllViews from a parent and add them one by one and invalidate again but that doesn't seem to work either.

There is probably a misunderstanding on my behalf as to how view inflation operates, shouldn't this work?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're inflating a completely new layout. You need to obtain the child views from the layout that's actually being used, e.g. `Activity.this.findViewById(int)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was indeed the problem. Sometimes the answer is right there. Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflating a layout creates a new view hierarchy, which means the views you're obtaining are actually different from the ones displayed on screen even though they have the same IDs.

You can obtain on-screen views in several ways, but the easiest would probably be to query the containing `Activity`.

```
Activity.this.findViewById(R.id.splash_Email);
```